# sed: Remove Line And Preceding Lines on Non-First Occurrance

Tags: sed

This better goes with an example (yes, from an .srt-file):

```
231
00:13:35,230 --> 00:13:37,120
- Oh, my sister got me into it.

232
00:13:37,129 --> 00:13:38,269
- Yeah?

233
00:13:37,129 --> 00:13:38,269
Is that her?

234
00:13:40,049 --> 00:13:41,090
- Yeah.
```

The line `00:13:37,129 --> 00:13:38,269` appears twice and I want to connect the two sections. So it would have to work like this:

- check all lines containing " --> "
- if it matches the previous such finding remove this line and the two lines above

So the result would be:

```
231
00:13:35,230 --> 00:13:37,120
- Oh, my sister got me into it.

232
00:13:37,129 --> 00:13:38,269
- Yeah?
Is that her?

234
00:13:40,049 --> 00:13:41,090
- Yeah.
```

This goes way beyond my `sed`-skills. It probably works with that internal buffer and pattern space? Well, I don't even have a clue how to approach this...

Comment: Why not awk but sed?

Comment: @oguzismail Well, I can't do backward things in awk, can I? I mean I don't care actually.

Comment: @oguzismail Oh, whow, cool. Don't be shy, make that an answer :)

Comment: Great, who downvoted my question and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use awk for that:

```
$ cat tst.awk
(!NF) {                # blank line
    b = ""; f = 1      # empty buffer, start buffering
}
/-->/ {                # timestamp
    f = 0              # stop buffering
    if (p == $0) {     # same timestamp
        next           # discard buffer, start over
    }
    p = $0             # save timestamp
    printf "%s", b     # print buffer
}
f {                    # buffering enabled
    b = (b $0 ORS)     # buffer line
    next               # start over
}
1                      # print line
```

outputs:

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
231
00:13:35,230 --> 00:13:37,120
- Oh, my sister got me into it.

232
00:13:37,129 --> 00:13:38,269
- Yeah?
Is that her?

234
00:13:40,049 --> 00:13:41,090
- Yeah.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the awk version is much better, but here is a bash version just for fun : )

```
out="";
while read line;
do
    if [ "$prevtime" != "$line" ];then
        out="${out}${line}\n";
    else
        out="$(echo -e "${out}"|head -n -2)\n";
    fi ;
    echo  "${line}" |grep -q  "\-\->" &&  prevtime=$line  ;
done <test.srt ; echo -e "$out"
```